# Nexus 5 error can't access to camera

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5, camera, google-camera

I have a Nexus 5 running android 6.0.1 and I'm using the google camera 3.2.045. After taking a picture and locking the phone just after, when i open my phone again i got a system message saying "can't access to camera" with 2 possibile options: ignore and report. So i closed the app, but every time I open it up again or I try to take a picture also with others app but i get the same message. What should I do?

Comment: Goto settings->apps, choose Google camera applicatiion. Inside `app info`, tap on `force stop`, and then choose storage section, `clear data` and `clear cache`. Open Google camera application and check. (Note: It will reset camera, your applied camera settings will lost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some bug, I had this problem to, but later it was disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, now stranger then usually.
What works now for in like 70% of the time is going on
`Options` --> `Apps` --> `Kamera` --> `Force Stop`. Reboot device if that doesn't work and try again☺

Hope this helps you :)